# Error uploading on Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: avrdude

I'm completely new to Arduino, I bought a Rampos 1.4 and an Arduino Mega 2560 to build a Prusa Mendel 3D printer.

But when I connect the Arduino via USB to my computer, open the software and click to upload the blink example, it does anything and says Uploading to i/o board.

This happens when I use Arduino 0022 and then when I use Arduino 1.0.5 r2 that is the problem:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

I don't know what is happening, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: you need to read the extremely comprehensive `getting started` documentation on the Arduino website. this is off-topic here as it is way to broad to teach the basics and fundamentals of working with an Arduino. this is about specific solvable questions, not *help teach me I don't want to read* type questions.

Comment: I searched on Google during 2 hours until make that post, I'm not of that people you say. Now I'm searching that getting started that you said.

Comment: And @JarrodRoberson, I'm not english and I had several mistakes to write and I to read. Is that what I have to read? http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows

Comment: I've done all the getting started, and it happened another time. I don't know what to do, now the port changed from COM12 to COM3, but it's still not working.

Comment: You need to select the proper board and port.

Comment: @TOMATO I've done it.

Comment: This question fits the subject scope of [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) better than that of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I do not have the reputation to comment. I think your problem can be because you selected the wrong settings for your board. Check in Tools option, and make sure Board, Processor and Port is correct.